# Can I color coding revisions in Rstudio

Tags: colors, rstudio

I am editing someone's code and would like to color code my changes- can I do this in Rstudio-- I know  I know GITHUB but........ I know about themes but this doesn't seem to offer what I want- I want to keep my code clearly identified in the revised version?
many thanks

Comment: I do not believe that is an option.